# jquery show and hide div based on 2 separate scroll positions

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I am trying to figure out how I can show/hide the same div in 2 different positions on the page but its currently not working correctly. I understand why my code isn't working but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 400) {
            $(".socialShare").hide();
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var banner = $(".articleBannerImg").offset().top;
        var bannerHeight = $(".articleBannerImg").outerHeight();
        if ($(window).width() < 400) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > (banner + bannerHeight)) {
                $(".socialShare").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $(".socialShare").fadeOut();
            } 
        }

        var article = $(".articleBody .copy").offset().top;
        var articleHeight = $(".articleBody .copy").outerHeight();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > (article + articleHeight)) {
            $(".socialShare").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(".socialShare").fadeIn();
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close enough to what I need to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 400) {
            $(".socialShare").hide();
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var article = $(".articleBody .copy").offset().top;
        var articleHeight = $(".articleBody .copy").outerHeight();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > (article + articleHeight)) {
            $(".socialShare").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(".socialShare").fadeIn();
        } 
    });
```